# Unable to run SQL Script in sqlplus using the system user

Tags: oracle, cmd, oracle11g

I'm new with this. I have to run script in sqlplus as the **system** user in command prompt. when I define path`( SQL> @<path>[filename.sql] )` and hit enter the error should be

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01119: error in creating database file
'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\EDM\TEST.DBF'
ORA-27040: file create error, unable to create file
OSD-04002: unable to open file
O/S-Error: (OS 3) The system cannot find the path specified.
```

how to solve this?

Comment: Looks like D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\EDM directory (or path) doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, Got It Thanks @Littlefoot